# sql query how to show rows which has the value CS but the whole row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey guys i need some help i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `author` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `howused` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `category` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email_ad` tinytext COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

and i have inserted those values

```
INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `image`, `title`, `author`, `howused`, `price`, `description`, `category`, `email_ad`) VALUES
(8, 'rsz_bilgisayar-donanimi.jpg', 'i realy dont know any books ', 'and authors', 'very_used', 150.05, 'Well it might be a good book but i dont really know ', 'BS', 'myemail@city.academic.gr'),
(30, 'High_Resolution-G413 Snow BOB RGB.png', 'just another test', 'justo another test ', 'very_used', 2, 'awdwa', 'ENG', 'afawf@mail.com'),
(61, 'me.jpg', 'afdwas', 'ad', 'very_used', 2, 'afefa', 'PSY', 'mail @asdadf.gr'),
(62, 'me.jpg', 'afdwas', 'ad', 'very_used', 2, 'afefa', 'PSY', ''mail @asdadf.gr'),
(63, 'me.jpg', 'afdwas', 'ad', 'very_used', 2, 'afefa', 'PSY', ''mail @asdadf.gr'),
(64, 'title2.png', 'Harry potter', 'kbasfhfae', 'kinda_used', 123, 'abawodfihapifubwa me mia gratsounia sth mesh', 'PSY', 'zksbfasfasnb@asfbn.com'),
(65, '', '', '', 'like_new', 0, '', 'CS', 'adawdwa'),
(66, 'me2.jpg', 'Harry potter', 'J.K. Rolling', 'kinda_used', 56.08, 'lancia', 'PSY', ''mail @asdadf.gr');
```

For example i am interesting to show the all the rows which values equals to CS. But not only the value CS i want the whole row

Comment: use this query: select * from images where category='CS'

Comment: what your tried so far . show the query @ChrisBi

Comment: this is simple select query..you would have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

To select all the columns in a query you use the syntax

```
SELECT * FROM `images`
```

the `*` means all.

To limit the results returned you use a WHERE clause

```
WHERE `category` = 'CS'
```

So the full query would be

```
SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `category` = 'CS'
```

If you know you only want specific columns returned then you name them in the select list like

```
SELECT title,author FROM `images` WHERE `category` = 'CS'
```

> SO is not really supposed to be a simple tutorial site. Start by reading an SQL tutorial
>
> Google `SQL tutorial` and you will get `2,750,000 results in about 0.46 seconds` Pick one and learn the basicas from there

Comment: typo : back tick on value `category` = 'CS`

Comment: @JYoThI Woops and on such a simple query. More caffine required :) Thanks

Comment: sorry mate i am under pressure thats why i asked help. let me explain a few things more. i have a table which containts information about a book. title, author, used or not and category. i want the query to locate the value CS from category and return to me the row with information of the book like title author

Comment: The * will return all columns, or you can name the columns. I amended my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. if i want to add more columns to my query i just put SELECT title,author,description,email FROM `images` WHERE `category` = 'CS'

Comment: Yep, you are getting the hang of ot now

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compare with all the fields then

```
select * 
from  images 
where (image like '%cs%' 
        OR title like '%cs%' 
        OR author like '%cs%' 
        OR howused like '%cs%' 
        OR price like '%cs%' 
        OR description like '%cs%' 
        OR category like '%cs%' 
        OR email_ad like '%cs%');`
```

or if you want to compare with only one field then

```
select * from images where category like '%cs%';`
```

Comment: This query will return only the value CS from category? right?

Comment: yes matching the values in that field, it will return the row even if the value of the category field is 'caste', as it is not matching the exact string.

Comment: As the OP knows that `CS` is in the `category` column and that it is EQUAL to `CS` then all that in the first query is totally unnecessary and a waste of execution time and the second simpler query could better use an `=`

Comment: let me explain a few things more. i have a table which containts information about a book. title, author, used or not and category. i want the query to locate the value CS from category and return to me the row with information of the book like title author.